# Loop through list of colors while maintaining order

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

Let's say I have a list of colors, such as

```
let ListOfColors = ["Red", "Blue", "Yellow"];
```

I need to iterate over it via a function that receives a number of elements to print, so that it behaves like this:

If the number of elements to print is 5, it should print

```
Red
Blue
Yellow
Red
Blue
```

As you can see, as soon as the current iteration exceeds the total number of colors, it starts again.

For the moment, this is what I have:

```
function TestColorIteration(NumberOfTimesToIterate)
{
    let ListOfColors = ["Red", "Blue", "Yellow"];

    for(let i = 0; i< NumberOfTimesToIterate; i++)
    {
       console.log(ListOfColors[i])
    }
}
```

But it does not start the cycle again, it prints undefined.

Answer (score 1):

The modulo operator (`%`) returns the remainder after integer division.

```js
function TestColorIteration(NumberOfTimesToIterate)
{
    let ListOfColors = ["Red", "Blue", "Yellow"];
    let Count = ListOfColors.length;

    for(let i = 0; i< NumberOfTimesToIterate; i++)
    {
       console.log(ListOfColors[i % Count])
    }
}
```

You were seeing `undefined` because the `i` index was growing to greater than the length of the array.
Trying to access an element outside the "bounds" of an array will return `undefined`.

Comment: This does work for this example, as the list is not empty. It should be noted that % performs division to return the remainder, so more generally, if the array happens to be empty, count will be zero, and thus `i % count` will be `NaN`.

Answer (score 0):

This is easier to implement with a while loop.

What is happening is you are reaching the last element in the array and then trying to get *more* elements, but there are no more elements which in turn gives you undefined.

You need to reset your "position" in the array once you have reached the max elements in the array.

```js
function TestColorIteration(NumberOfTimesToIterate)
{
    let ListOfColors = ["Red", "Blue", "Yellow"];
    
    let counter = 0;
    let listElem = 0;
    
    while(counter < NumberOfTimesToIterate)
    {
      console.log(ListOfColors[listElem]);
      
      counter++;
      listElem++;
      
      if(counter == ListOfColors.length)
      {
        listElem = 0;
      }
      
    }

}

TestColorIteration(5);
```

Answer (score -1):

The simplest solution is by using two loops.

```
function TestColorIteration(NumberOfTimesToIterate)
{
    let ListOfColors = ["Red", "Blue", "Yellow"];
    var fullRounds = Math.floor(NumberOfTimesToIterate/ListOfColors.length)
    var remainder  = NumberOfTimesToIterate%ListOfColors.length

    for(let i = 0; i< fullRounds; i++)
    {
       console.log(ListOfColors[0])
       console.log(ListOfColors[1])
       console.log(ListOfColors[2])
    }

    for(let i = 0; i< remainder; i++)
    {
       console.log(ListOfColors[i])
    }
}
```